# Froeign Key Reference

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have two tables with primary key and foreign key relation ship.Below are table structure.

```
Master Table
------------
create table phrase(id varchar(50) constraint phrase_pk primary key,name varchar(50))

Child Table
-----------
create table phrase_child(phrase_id varchar(50) constraint pharse_child_pharse foreign key references phrase(id))

Insert into phrase values('1','A');
Insert into phrase values('2','B')
Insert into phrase values('3','C')


insert into phrase_child values('1,2,3')
```

it is showing below error message when i tried to insert the above records in child table.
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "pharse_child_pharse".

```
Is it possible to insert like that in some other way using constraint?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into phrase_child 
values ('1'),('2'),('3')
```

Comment: Above statement insert values in separate rows(one by one).i think it will not insert values in same row like 1,2,3.i am trying to insert in same row(1,2,3) in the child table.

Comment: No, this is not possible as foreign key and you should absolutely never do this. Never store multiple values in a single column. Never!!! That would be a major design flaw.